# How to install TensorFlow on Buildroot?

Tags: linux, tensorflow, deep-learning, shared-libraries, buildroot

I'm trying to install Tensorflow on the embedded Linux [Buildroot](https://buildroot.org/).

Unfortunately I do not have a correct approach. It would be best if I had TensorFlow C++ as header only library.

Does anyone have experience and how much memory does the TensorFlow C++ library need?

Best regards

Fohlen

Comment: How is tensorflow different than other software packages? Is there a particular point that makes porting it harder? Have a look at the `packages`/ dir of Buildroot for some inspiration, and try to make your own example packages. Have a look at this minimal example potentially: https://github.com/cirosantilli/buildroot/tree/in-tree-package-2017.11